# mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd, rewrite, regex

I need a mod_rewrite rule that sends all requests to index.php unless the request is for anything in the /media/ folder.

I have a similar rule for lighttpd but I don't know enough about regex/mod_rewrite to change it for Apache.

```
        url.rewrite-once = (
            "/(media)/(.*)" => "/$1/$2",
            "^([^\?]*)(\?(.+))?$" => "/index.php?url=$1&$3",
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making some corrections to Redmumba's answer...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap esc int:escape
RewriteCond $0 !^/media/
RewriteRule .* /index.php?url=$0\%3f${esc:%{QUERY_STRING}} [B]
```

Use the `$0` backreference rather than `%{PATH_INFO}` to refer to the input path.  In the `RewriteRule`, add the `B` flag to escape the URL again (as explained in the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)).  The rest of the rule is there to double-escape the original query string, so that it can be recovered when the `url` parameter is unescaped by your `index.php`.

Alternatively, if your `index.php` expects to use its query string directly rather than decoding it from within the `url` parameter, you would use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $0 !^/media/
RewriteRule .* /index.php?url=$0 [B,QSA]
```

This is actually a more faithful translation of your LighTTPD rewrite rule, but you run the risk of a conflict in case the input query string contains a `url` parameter itself.

Comment: +1 for the query escaping; I didn't even think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're going to be doing the same exact things, only calling `RewriteRule` instead of `url.rewrite-once`.  Also, one improvement that could be made to both is to use a `RewriteCond` to match the media part.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} !^/media/.*
RewriteRule ^([^\?]*)(\?(.+))?$ /index.php?url=$1&$3
```

This way, you're not having to rewrite the rule for /media--this checks to see if it doesn't begin with `/media` and rewrites it.  If it does, it just passes it along.

Hope this helps!